# Filter results from a laravel collection based on the related record

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I'm using https://github.com/nicolaslopezj/searchable in my Laravel Project.

I have a Hotel object with a many to many relationships with Users.

I can query the relationship using this:

```
protected $searchable = [
    'columns' => [
        'hotels.nombre' => 10
    ],
    'joins' => [
        'hotel_user' => ['hotels.id' , 'hotel_id'],
        'users' => ['hotel_user.user_id', 'users.id']
    ]
];
```

The search returns something like this (json format)

```
 [
  {
    "id": 3,
    "nombre": "Paradisus Playa del Carmen La Esmeralda",
    "url_foto": "uploads/hotel/3/1484747239.jpg",
    "website_url": "https://www.melia.com/es/hoteles/mexico/playa-del-carmen/home.htm",
    "updated_at": "2017-01-18 13:47:44",
    "relevance": 60,
    "users": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Alex",
        "last_name": "Angelico",
        "formatted_name": "Alex",
        "company": "ConexionBIZ",
        "title": "Director",
        "picture_url": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_FIUn3Wf5E4OMEwzR5feW3o7IoRSveSkR5W7d3oxczOM5BdPUwDws7EIJXvDEIE5c6HMeaSSFgb19",
        "created_at": "2017-01-17 12:00:00",
        "updated_at": "2017-01-18 13:50:19",
        "pivot": {
          "hotel_id": 3,
          "user_id": 1,
          "created_at": null,
          "updated_at": null
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

I want to filter all the hotels belonging to some particular user. 
I tried:

```
 $result = \App\Hotel::search($request->get('q'))->with([
            'users' => function($q) use ($user_id) {
                $q->where('users.id', '<>', $user_id);
            },
        ])->get();
```

But this returns the hotel without the related user. I need to remove the HOTEL (not just the USER) from the results.

How can I do this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `with()` method is actually ran as a second query after the `Hotel` collection is retrieved and is used for lazy loading.

What you're looking for is the `whereHas()` which will filter the current model results based on a related model.

```
$result = \App\Hotel::search($request->get('q'))
    ->whereHas('users', function($q) use ($user_id) {
        $q->where('users.id', '<>', $user_id);
    })
    ->get();
```

That will return all `Hotel` models that have users that don't match `$user_id`.

If you need to load the users too then:

```
$result = \App\Hotel::search($request->get('q'))
    ->with('users')
    ->whereHas('users', function($q) use ($user_id) {
        $q->where('users.id', '<>', $user_id);
    })
    ->get();
```

That will load all `Hotel` models that have at least 1 user not matching `$user_id` but the `$result->first()->users` collection can still contain users with that id.  To not return any `Hotel` models that have `$user_id` and to not return any users in the related collection you would combine both methods:

```
$result = \App\Hotel::search($request->get('q'))
    ->with(['users' => function($q) use ($user_id) {
        $q->where('users.id', '<>', $user_id);
    }])
    ->whereHas('users', function($q) use ($user_id) {
        $q->where('users.id', '<>', $user_id);
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: BTW, I'm new to Laravel and I'm having difficulties finding good documentation. The Laravel's site seems unsufficient to me, and Laracast was good for starting, but now... Do you have some advise for good documentation or literature about Laravel 5.3? TKS!

Comment: The majority of my knowledge comes from the Laravel documentation.  I recommend reading through their documentation thoroughly once to give you a higher level overview so when you run into things you have a general idea of if/where the documentation covers it.  Once you learn the naming conventions and basically the "Laravel" way, the documentation becomes easier to navigate.  Feel free to hit me up if you have questions too. I'm always willing to help a fellow developer!  Cheers!